# Write to next column CSV module Python

Tags: python, csv

I already looked for answers, all I want is if it sees that (if `description` in `readline`) write the data in the next column where the active cell is, not in the next row.

Here is the sample that I already got:

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhkHw.png)
[This is the current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2WOI.png)

```
row = 1

while True:
    result = crt.Screen.WaitForStrings( waitStrs )

    if result == 2:
        break

    screenrow = crt.Screen.CurrentRow - 1
    readline = crt.Screen.Get(screenrow, 1, screenrow, 80)
    items = readline.split(':')

    # Split the line ( ":" delimited) and put some fields into Excel
    if 'interface ' in readline:
        worksheet.writerow(items[:1])
        ++row
    elif ' description' in readline \
        or ' ip address' in readline \
        or ' port allow' in readline \
        or 'binding' in readline:
            worksheet.writerow(items[:1])  # <--(write this data in the next column where the active cell is)
```

Sample data:

```
Info
interface Aux0/0/1
inferface Vlanif30
 description Publc Link to CX600-3-B
 ip address 10.132.10.132 255.255.255.252
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample snippet of your csv input-file? What do you want to fill the empty cells in the output with?

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample data given below my snippet should do the job. For further explanation please see comments in code. The documentation of Python's csv module can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html).

Sample data:

```
Info
interface Aux0/0/1
inferface Vlanif30
 description Public Link to CX600-3-B
 ip address 10.132.10.132 255.255.255.252
```

---

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import csv

description_index = None
before_description = []
after_description = []

# Open input file and read each line
with open('data.csv') as infile:
        lines = infile.read().splitlines()

# Iterate through read lines and look for ' description'
# since we need to split output format based on this line number
for lno, line in enumerate(lines):
    if ' description' in line:
        description_index = lno

# if there is no ' description' we do not want to change output format
# and write all data to a row each.
# In order to do so, we set description_index to the length of the lines list.
if not description_index:
    description_index = len(lines)

# Knowing the line number of ' description' gives us the
# possibility to divide lines into two parts
before_description = lines[:description_index]
after_description = lines[description_index:]

# Open output file, init a csvwriter and write data.
# Since a row is defined by a list passed to the writer
# we iterate through the lines before the ' description'
# and cast each element as a list before passing it to the csvwriter.
# Since the part after ' description' should be in one row we write all
# all elements to a single list.
# Since we do not want to write empty lines, we check if each element exists.
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    outputwriter = csv.writer(outfile)
    for element in before_description:
        if element:
            outputwriter.writerow([element])
    outputwriter.writerow([element for element in after_description if element])
```

---

Output (comma-separated csv-file):

```
Info
interface Aux0/0/1
inferface Vlanif30
 description Public Link to CX600-3-B, ip address 10.132.10.132 255.255.255.252
```